# Linq query takes far too long

Tags: vb.net, linq

Please see the code below:

```
 Dim listPersonExact As List(Of type1) = ISystem1.GetMatches(getExclusions()) '1    
        Dim checks = From t1 In listPersonExact _
            Join t2 In listCheckedMerges On t1.MasterID Equals t2.MasterID And t1.ChildID Equals t2.ChildID _
            Select New With {t1.MasterID, t1.ChildID, t1.MergeTypeID}
        Dim listCheckedMerges As List(Of type1) = ISystem1.GetMatches


        For Each var In checks
            MsgBox('Got here')
        Next
```

The ForEach is reached very quickily.  However, it takes a very long time to move from For Each to the message box.  Is there any way I can optimise this?

**Update**
Following on from Tim Shmelters comment I have written the following as a test:

```
Public Shared Sub LinqTest()
        Dim t1 As New TestPerson
        t1.id = 1
        t1.name = "Ian"

        Dim t2 As New TestPerson
        t2.id = 2
        t2.name = "Lauren"

        Dim list As List(Of TestPerson) = New List(Of TestPerson)
        list.Add(t1)
        list.Add(t2)

        Dim list2 As List(Of TestPerson) = New List(Of TestPerson)
        list2.Add(t1)

        Dim test = From p1 In list Join p2 In list2 On New With {p1.id, p1.name} Equals New With {p2.id, p2.name} Where t1.id = t2.id And t1.name = t2.name Select p1.id, p1.name
        For Each var In test
            MsgBox(var.id)
            MsgBox(var.name)
        Next


    End Sub
```

I would expect the FOR loop to loop once, however it does not loop.  Why is this?

Comment: That's LINQ's deferred execition. The query `checks` itself just defines how it will be executed. The `For Each` will actually execute it.

Comment: Apart from that, your LINQ query should not compile. You can't use `And` in the join condition. Use an anonymous type if you want to join on multiple columns/properties.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I have edited the question.  Could you take a look?

Comment: Now you're changing the question. What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

> The ForEach is reached very quickily. However, it takes a very long
>   time to move from For Each to the message box.

That's LINQ's [deferred execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/). The query itself just defines how it will be executed. The `For Each` will actually execute it.

<strike>But it should not compile at all. You can't use `And` in the join condition.</strike> Use an anonymous type if you want to join on multiple columns/properties.

---

According to this hint you've tried following:

```
Dim test = From p1 In list Join p2 In list2 
           On New With {p1.id, p1.name} Equals New With {p2.id, p2.name} 
           Where t1.id = t2.id And t1.name = t2.name 
           Select p1.id, p1.name
```

> I would expect the FOR loop to loop once, however it does not loop.
>   Why is this?

In VB.NET you have to define the [keys of an anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) (as opposed to C# where all properties are the keys automatically). Otherwise only references are compared.

So this should work(note that your `Where` is redundant):

```
Dim test = From p1 In list Join p2 In list2 
           On New With {Key p1.id, Key p1.name} Equals New With {Key p2.id, Key p2.name}
           Select New With {Key p1.id, Key p1.name}
```

Comment: Tim, this `And` syntax is valid: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx. In the second snippet OP uses variable names `t1` & `t2` instead of range variables. Not surprising they don't match.

Comment: @GertArnold: whoops, i didn't know that it's valid in VB.NET. Since when is it supported? But if he uses the anonymous type approach he has to use the `Key`-keyword, otherwise two anonymous types are not compared by values but only by references(which is of course not the same). I guess OP uses the `t1` and `t2` values in the `Where` as additional filters.

Comment: As for me, since 5 minutes ago :)

Comment: Yes, the structural comparison difference with C# is important. It bugs me a bit thought that the OP changed the question. Do they still want to know something about performance? Who knows.

Comment: @GertArnold: maybe i've always used the C# version using anonymous types also in VB because i didn't know that you can use `And` in VB.NET. Actually it was always supported. I wonder how it is implemented. I guess they use also an anonymous type, at least in Linq-To-Objects.

Comment: Thanks for the LINQ query.  It works.  +1.  There are about 100,000 records in both lists.  Is a linq query going to be too slow?

Comment: @w0051977: the `Join` is pretty efficient since it uses a set based approach under the hood. But two lists with 100000 items is a lot to compare. What are the datasources, why can't you filter and link there(f.e. in a database)? Do you have enough memory, have you checked it? Maybe the swapfile must be used already.